# Downvoted a question accidentally

Tags: support, questions, down-votes, undo

I accidentally downvoted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968753/windows-2008-r2-file-sharing-access-denied-if-groups-are-specified-in-acl), which I didn't mean that.  It must be because I used my iphone this afternoon and I didn't close my browser when I put my iphone back to my pocket.

I want to undo it but it was done more than 5 hours ago.  I feel really sorry for the person who asked the question.  How can I undo it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make a minor edit, if necessary requested via a comment, and then you'll be able to remove it.

Wait, you don't have enough rep for this. Well, I did a minor edit, you must now be able to remove your downvote.

Comment: I don't think I can edit his question.  Can I?

Comment: Yes, I realized this. See answer update :)

Comment: Edit his answer so I'll be able to undo my downvote? Sounds like a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: @sq33G only solution is totally removing the block and allowing one to change votes without any restriction, and that would cause much more harm than good thus will never happen. So all we have are workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing to improve in the question (thus edit won't be proper), you can apologize to the OP by a comment and ask that if and when edit occurs, notify you as well (via comment reply) so that you can reverse the vote.

Also, you can go through other posts of that user (questions or answers) and upvote what you deem correct and helpful.

All in all, it's really not the end of the world - mistakes happen, single downvote won't really change anything.